# Click link to send a text message in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, links, sms

We are making extensive use of Google Sheets' `HYPERLINK` formula combined with **mailto** links to create links in cells that will dynamically generate emails. For example:

```
=HYPERLINK(
    "mailto:test@test.com" &
        "?cc=support@test.com" &
        "&subject=Test email" &
        "&body=This is a test email.",
    "Send email"
)
```

That will create linked text that, when clicked, will create an email in your default email client.  Naturally we can easily make that dynamic by replacing the hard-coded values with cell references:

```
=HYPERLINK(
    "mailto:" & $C2 &
        "?cc=" & $D2 &
        "&subject=" & $E2 &
        "&body=" & $F2,
    "Send email"
)
```

We were hoping to do the same thing with [**sms** links](http://thenewcode.com/856/Send-a-SMS-Text-From-A-Link), but none of the following result in a clickable link:

```
=HYPERLINK("sms:", "Send SMS")
=HYPERLINK("sms:19875550198", "Send SMS")
=HYPERLINK("sms:+19875550198", "Send SMS")
=HYPERLINK("sms://19875550198", "Send SMS")
=HYPERLINK("sms://+19875550198", "Send SMS")
```

So it seems that the `HYPERLINK` formula doesn't recognize **sms** links the way it recognizes **mailto** links.

Is there a way to do this in Google Sheets?

Answer (score 4):

From the documentation for `HYPERLINK`: "Only certain link types are allowed. http://, https://, mailto:, aim:, ftp://, gopher://, telnet://, and news:// are permitted; **others are explicitly forbidden** (my emphasis)."

As you can see, `sms` is not listed so one might reasonably assume that it is explicitly forbidden

Why `aim:` is included, I don't know, since AIM was discontinued in 2017.

A quick Google will yield any number of Add-ons and/or vendor services that will enable `sms`, but that is outside the scope of webapps.

Answer (score 3):

[Tedinoz's answer](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/159096/217314) points out which link types are allowed within `HYPERLINK`, which made me realize that I can use a permitted **https://** link to a simple HTML page with some JavaScript that forwards to an **sms** link.

Here's the code of the HTML page:

```
<!doctype html>

<html>
    <head>
        <title>HTTPS to SMS</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <script>
            // Based on https://stackoverflow.com/a/901144/1652620
            const urlSearchParams = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search);
            const params = Object.fromEntries(urlSearchParams.entries());

            function getParameterByName(name, url = window.location.href) {
                name = name.replace(/[\[\]]/g, '\\$&');
                var regex = new RegExp('[?&]' + name + '(=([^&#]*)|&|#|$)'),
                    results = regex.exec(url);
                if (!results) return null;
                if (!results[2]) return '';
                return decodeURIComponent(results[2].replace(/\+/g, ' '));
            }

            var tel = getParameterByName('tel');
            var body = getParameterByName('body');

            // Based on https://stackoverflow.com/a/4745622/1652620
            if (tel != "" && tel != null) {
                window.location = "sms://+" + tel + ";?&body=" + body;
            }
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

So say you save that as `sms.html` and upload it to `https://www.someurl.com/sms.html`. You then just add a query string with values for `tel` and optionally `body`, which can be generated as needed in Google Sheets.

The final formula in Google Sheets would then look something like this:

```
=HYPERLINK("https://www.someurl.com/sms.html?tel=19875550198&body=This%20is%20a%20test%20message.", "Send SMS")
```

Or, with cell references:

```
=HYPERLINK("https://www.someurl.com/sms.html?tel=" & A2 & "&body=" & B2, "Send SMS")
```

where `A2` contains the phone number and `B2` contains the [URL-encoded](https://www.urlencoder.org/) body text.

It's not quite the elegant in-app solution I was hoping for, but it gets the job done, if indirectly.